# Gmail Email Markup validates and passes SPF but fails to render

Tags: google-schemas, google-inbox

I'm using the [Parcel Delivery schema](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery) and have had success all the way up to the point of rendering correctly inside Google Inbox. I'm still at the point of testing so I'm sending email from fixme@gmail.com to fixme@gmail.com which should be enough to test the implementation.

1. The email content & schema passes the [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester)
2. The email content & schema works correctly when using the [App Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial). The email arrives in my inbox and renders correctly
3. The email content & schema works correctly when using the [App Engine Tool](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/). The email arrives in my inbox and renders correctly
4. I've sent email where the 'to' and 'from' email addresses are the same
5. SPF and DKIM both pass when I inspect the email sent

[image]

Kind of stumped with little to go with to assist with debugging.

Worth noting that I use Mailgun to deliver email from my service.

Comment: I just noticed that DMARC is failing. Not sure why but I also don't see that as a requirement in the Google Developer documentation.

Comment: I notice that if I send it to my email address on my Google Apps account - which matches the Mailgun account - there is no DMARC. The markup still fails to render.

Comment: What are the error that you encounter? Do you have any error logs?

Comment: @abielita there are no errors (although there's no interface for such a thing in gmail/inbox so i'm not exactly sure what you're referring to. the email sends fine. it's just the markup that does not render. the same markup works correctly when it is sent via one of Google's three testing frameworks.

Comment: @Greg did your register your email/domain for Gmail Schemas? It sounds like you're on the right track, you just need to be whitelisted for the feature to use with your email/domain. You can register at the following link https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google. I hope this helps.

Comment: I hadn't done that yet. There was an implication in the docs that this wasn't required for email sent from a gmail account. But registration is the next move. Thanks.